# How can I return a value from the row after the one that matches a condition?

Tags: r

How can I return a value from a row that immediately follows one which satisfies a specific condition?

For example, let's say I have this dataset

```
ID    Colour    Result
1     red       positive
2     blue      positive
3     NA        void
4     green     negative
```

reproduced here:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
               Colour = c("red", "blue", NA, "green"),
               Result = c("positive", "positive", "void", "negative")),
          row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

I want to be able to say, if `Result == "void"`, then tell me what the value of `Colour` is in the row immediately afterwards.

So if I run such a function over this dataset, it should return `green`, as it is the colour that belongs to the row after the `void` row.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try the base R ifelse function along with the dplyr lag and lead functions

Comment: I have reworded the question to make it clearer. In simple terms, where there is a `void` present, I want to know the `Colour` value of the next row.

Comment: @Mus Why not just filter out all the `NA`s (or `"void"`s) via `dplyr::filter(dataset, !is.na(Colour))` (or `dplyr::filter(dataset, !is.na(Result != "void))`)?  Thing is, if you have multiple `"void"`s, that function will be ambiguous...unless you want a vector like `c("green", ...)` returned.

Comment: Hi, the answer can be simple but the question needs to be explained more clearly,
1. you want to check only for void rows containing void ,
2. what if your void row is last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `which` is natural:

```
dataset$Colour[1+which(dataset$Result == 'void')]
```

evaluates to `"green"`.

Comment: This approach makes sense. How would this work within a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about `fill` from `tidyr`?

```
df <- read_table("ID    Colour    Result
1     red       positive
2     blue      positive
3     NA        void
4     green     negative")

> df %>% fill(Colour, .direction = "up")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID Colour Result  
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   
1     1 red    positive
2     2 blue   positive
3     3 green  void    
4     4 green  negative
```

Or if it needs to be based on the Result column, then `lead` from `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(Colour = ifelse(
         Result == "void", 
         lead(Colour), 
         Colour))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID Colour Result  
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   
1     1 red    positive
2     2 blue   positive
3     3 green  void    
4     4 green  negative
```